# How to resize HTML element relative to its actual size on the page

Tags: html, css

I would like to find the CSS definition that would let me take the actual height of an element and subtract a fixed amount from it.

So if the element happens to have a height of `200px` (because of the dynamic content in it) I would like to have the height updated to 200-H (where H is a fixed number).

I tried using

```
height: calc(100% - 20px)
```

But it doesn't look like the `100%` actually refers to the dynamic height of the element

Comment: I haven&#39;t used calc before but the measurement 100% is of the parent element (or the closest explicitly sized parent or something) not the element itself. You might have to wrap the element in another but it does sound like the kind of thing that can be achieved another way - what is the effect you&#39;re going for? Or look into CSS preprocessors which while overkill for one issue might be another good tool in the long run

Comment: You could also use negative margins and z-index to hide part of the element under the element above or below.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to avoid using javaScript to get the dynamic object's dimensions. If so, you have to control the height throughout the DOM, right down to the container div of your dynamic object. This should work:

```
html{height:100%;}
body{height:100%;}
div{
    border: 1px solid green; /* just to test your output */
    width:100px;
    height: calc(50% + 20px);
    height: -moz-calc(50% + 20px);
    height: -ms-calc(50% + 20px);
    height: -o-calc(50% + 20px);
    height: -webkit-calc(50% + 20px);
}
```

Note that html, body, and anything else "above" the div has the height designated as 100%.

Hoping this helps.

Edit: it's also important to have the various webkit designations as well.